# Associated Properties: How to Avoid an Infinite Loop

Tags: c#, infinite-loop

I have a Cube class. The cube can be constrained so that the `width=height=length`. I've coded this functionality but as you can see, my code results in a circular/infinite loop - `the width sets the height which sets the width which sets the height and so on`.

How can I make my Cube class constrained and avoid this infinite loop? Is my only solution to use a boolean variable `propagate` (see below)?

```
public class Cube {

    public bool isConstrained {get; set;} // if constrained then width=height=length

    // Causes a circular problem. How can I avoid this? Maybe create a variable private bool propagate = false; ??
    public double width
    {
        get { return width;  } 
        set 
        { 
            width  = value; 
            if (isConstrained) 
            {
                 height = value;
                 length = value; 
            }  
        } 
    }

    public double height
    { 
        get { return height;  } 
        set 
        {   
             height  = value; 
             if (isConstrained) 
             { 
                 width = value;
                 length = value; 
             } 
        } 
    }

    public double length
    {
         get { return length;  }
         set
         { 
              length  = value;  
              if (isConstrained) 
              { 
                  height = value; 
                  width = value; 
              } 
         } 
    }
}
```

My only solution is this:

```
private bool propagate = true;

public double length
{
    get { return length;  } 
    set 
    {
         length  = value; 
         if (isConstrained && propagate) 
         { 
             propagate = false;
             height = value; 
             width = value; 
             propagate = true;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not private fields?

Comment: @Mephy I dont quite understand how this would solve my problem? My goal is for people to be able to set the cubes properties from the outside (public) but when the cube is constrained and I set the width I want the height and length to change also (to width value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently even just your getters will give a stack overflow - you don't have any fields backing your data, because you're not using automatically-implemented properties. Additionally, your properties don't have conventional names, which is definitely worth fixing.

You should just use private fields to back the properties, and set those accordingly within your property setters. That way no property will call another, and all will be well... except for the design being a bit troublesome to start with. (When changing one property changes another, that can be surprising.)

So something like:

```
private int width;
private int height;
private int length;
private bool constrained;
...

public int Width
{
    get { return width; }
    set
    {
        width = value;
        if (constrained)
        {
            height = value;
            length = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thats a good solution, I was hoping there was a more elegant way to solve it though - because this solution involves 2 'variables/properties' for width, for height, for length, for etc.

Comment: @MillieSmith lol yes a cube should but again I'll need another class for polygon. This way I can have 1 class a `Cube` (I should rename it to `Polygon`) that can either be a cube or polygon

Comment: A polygon is 2d and a cube is 3d. You don't want to use the same class to represent them.. I wouldn't even extend one from the other

Comment: @JakeM: It involves one variable and one property for each value. That makes perfect sense to me. In what way would anything be more elegant? Do you understand that even without using `constrained`, your current code is simply broken? You can *only* get away with a single property declaration for the combination of variable and property if you're using automatically implemented variables.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't a cube always have the length, width, and height be the same? You could use a single private variable to hold the length, width, and height, and then when setting any of those Properties, assign that value to the private variable. Return the value of that same variable in the get Properties for width/height/length.